# Specialize template functor over template class

Tags: c++, templates, functor

Let's say I have a template functor :

```
template <class U, class V>
struct Converter
{
    V& operator() (const U&, V&) const;
};
```

I want to "specialize" this converter over a template class and a non-template class :

```
template<>
struct Converter <template<class> MyTemplateClass, MyNonTemplateClass>
{
    //I can't use MyTemplateClass without specializing it 
    //even if I don't need it to perform the computation
};
```

Of course, this can't work. How would you do to achieve a similar result ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to move the type for `template<class> MyTemplateClass` up in template declaration for `Converter`.

```
template<class T>
struct Converter <MyTemplateClass<T>, MyNonTemplateClass>
{
    //...
};
```

Comment: This is called *"partial template specialization"*

Comment: I was curious about the inference capability of my compiler...And it worked very well (I did'nt need to specify the T class). Thanks again !